# Listado de sombreros del evento Winter Bash

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2016

¿Hay alguna lista de los sombreros que se pueden conseguir con el evento "Winter Bash"? y ¿los requisitos para conseguirlos?

Comment: para que sirven los sombreros?

Comment: son para poner en la foto de perfil, échale un ojo a este [post](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1159/14088)

Comment: Via bing: http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=es&a=http%3A%2F%2Fwinterbash2016.stackexchange.com%2F

Comment: Muchas gracias @MarcGravell !!

Comment: Yo conozco todos los sombreros secretos. ¿Cuánto pagas? (⌐■_■)

Comment: @Konamiman jajajajajjaj eso no vale, tu tienes enchufe!!!

Comment: @Konamiman si pago es para que me los des todos directamente no para saber cuales son jajajajaja

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Sí

Existe la página oficial del evento [Winter Bash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

Además, en la pregunta de Meta Stack Exchange [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/209901) puedes encontrar respuestas en las que se listan los sombreros que se pueden ganar:

- [sombreros secretos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/209901) - se va editando a medida que la gente los descubre
- [sombreros conocidos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/209901)

Comment: Votadme mucho, a ver si consigo el sombrero 24 por ganar una medalla de oro :D

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Ya te he votado jajajaaj, votarme a mi también ya que estamos